# Transform an input matrix into an output that replaces the original elements with their cumulative value

Tags: r, matrix

Hello Stack Overflow R community. I'm trying to write a function in RStudio version 1.3.1073 for Mac, that transforms the elements of a matrix, such that it replaces the original elements with their cumulative frequency value, in a matrix of the same dimension.

Say I have a matrix M:

```
matrix(c(50, 50, 54, 61, 50,
         61, 58, 59, 60, 65,
         54, 55, 58, 51, 60,
         58, 59, 66, 62, 51), nrow = 4, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) -> M

return(M)
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,]    50     50     54     61     50
[2,]    61     58     59     60     65
[3,]    54     55     58     51     60
[4,]    58     59     66     62     51
```

If I use `table(M)` then I get this output:

```
table(M)

50 51 54 55 58 59 60 61 62 65 66 
3  2  2  1  3  2  2  2  1  1  1
```

This table highlights the frequency of each element in M. The cumulative values for each would be:

```
50 51 54 55 58 59 60 61 62 65 66 
3  5  7  8  11 13 15 17 18 19 20
```

Ultimately, I am looking to obtain this transformed matrix TM:

```
return(TM)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    7   17    3
[2,]   17   11   13   15   19
[3,]    7    8   11    5   15
[4,]   11   13   20   18    5
```

Where each original element from the input matrix M is replaced by its calculated cumulative value as an output within the same cell for the new matrix TM.

I'm looking to avoid using packages, in case I need to use this function on a school computer that doesn't have internet access to load R packages. What should my approach be?

Thank you for your consideration, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @akrun for catching the errors in the output, I've updated my question to reflect these changes, as well as subsequent values resulting from this correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a named vector to match the values in 'M' and then replace the values in the matrix by assignment

```
M1 <- M
M1[] <- cumsum(table(M))[as.character(M)]
```

The output of `table` is a named 1d vector

```
str(table(M))
#'table' int [1:11(1d)] 3 2 2 1 3 2 2 2 1 1 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
#  ..$ M: chr [1:11] "50" "51" "54" "55" ...
```

With `cumsum`, the attribute `table` is dropped, but it is still a named `vector`

```
str(cumsum(table(M)))
# Named int [1:11] 3 5 7 8 11 13 15 17 18 19 ...
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "50" "51" "54" "55" ...
```

Now, any named vector can be matched with another vector (a `matrix` is a vector with some `dim` attributes) by matching the `names` with the corresponding elements of the `matrix` 'M'.  In `R`, if we use numeric values, it will be taken as a numeric index i.e. '50' => 50th element, 54 => 54th element.  We avoid that by converting to `character` (`as.character`).  Now, it is matching with the corresponding `names` of the vector to replace those values.  Note that the output is a named `vector` as well.  In order to convert to the original matrix dim, use assignment with `[]` so that the attributes are preserved

Comment: Thank you, and I appreciate your help. I've been able to implement this code into my final product and it works well and what I needed. 

Can you elaborate more on how this works? I'm relatively new to R and want to learn more about the reason your solution worked for me.

Comment: @Gadao I added some explanation.  Hope it helps